# .gitignore how to ignore a folder but not a subfolder

Tags: node.js, angular, git

I have the following project setup:

- A node backend server in the root folder. This is the folder under git control
- The node server serves the files in public/dist/subproject
- The Angular project is in the public subfolder. There is a separate git control for this folder

I use heroku as CI environment. It automatically builds from the github repository of my node project. Of course I would like to exclude the Angular sources (public folder) from my node git, but I want to explicitly include the public/dist/subproject folder because it contains the production build of my Angular frontend. But I cannot seem to get this working ...

This is what I tried for my node .gitignore

```
node_modules/*
public/*
!public/dist
public/dist/*
!public/dist/subproject
```

but git keeps ignoring the public/dist/subproject folder ... how can I manage to do this?

Comment: Unrelated answer, but if you make everything in your `angular.json` build to a subfolder, then you can just ignore those projects except the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after painful testing ...

The problem is that my Angular project has its own `.gitignore` in the public folder of the node project. This ignores the dist subfolder (of course it does).

But: git of the node project also uses this `.gitignore` in addition to its own. I had to remove `dist/*` from the Angular .gitignore in order to enable the node git to include this subfolder ...

So the actual question would be: **Can git be configured to only use the main `.gitignore` and not those in subfolders?**

Comment: Why don't you just delete the .gitignore in the subfolder?

Comment: Or else add the gitignore of the subfolder to the gitignore of the root, and remove the gitignore in the subfolder from sourcecontrol.

Comment: This won't work because the Angular project in public folder needs to have its own .gitignore